# disable mouse click on grid when ext.window is open extjs 3

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a Ext.GridPanel and a Ext.Window for changing the value of the clicked row of the Grid Panel. What I would like to do is disable the mouse click (both left and right) on the grid till the ext window is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unclear whether you are saying disable when the window is open or closed, as you say both, between the title and the question.

However, if you are referring to when the window is open, your best bet is to make the window modal, so the grid below is masked while the window is up.

just add the following to your window config

```
{
  ...
  modal: true,
  ..
}
```